# Checkout Form submission using ajax

Tags: php, jquery, mysqli

I want to submit my form using ajax, My script code does not have any errors also my php but when i click the submit button nothing happens, just form will empty otherwise nothing happened, the data does not store in the database. I don't know what the error is. I don't Know how to find it, Can anyone please help me to fix this?

```
  <div class="container-fluid">
                <h3 class="alert alert-success" align="center">CHECKOUT FORM</h3>
                <form id="checkout_form">
                <div class="row">

                        <div class="col-md-2">

                        </div>

                        <div class="col-md-4">
                            <div class="form-group">
                              <label for="usr">Name:</label>
                              <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" name="name">
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                              <label for="email">Email:</label>
                              <input type="text" class="form-control" id="email" name="email">
                            </div>
                             <div class="form-group">
                              <label for="address">Address:</label>
                              <input type="text" class="form-control" id="address" name="address">
                            </div>
                             <div class="form-group">
                              <label for="city">City:</label>
                              <input type="text" class="form-control" id="city" name="city">
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                              <label for="city">State:</label>
                              <input type="text" class="form-control" id="state" name="state">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-4">
                            <div class="form-group">
                              <label for="card">Card Name:</label>
                              <input type="text" class="form-control" id="card_name" name="card_name">
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                              <label for="cvv">CVV:</label>
                              <input type="text" class="form-control" id="cvv" name="cvv">
                            </div>
                             <div class="form-group">
                              <label for="card_num">Card Number:</label>
                              <input type="text" class="form-control" id="card_number" name="card_number">
                            </div>
                             <div class="form-group">
                              <label for="expired_month">Expire Month:</label>
                              <input type="text" class="form-control" id="expired_month" name="expired_month">
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                              <label for="zip">Zip Code:</label>
                              <input type="text" class="form-control" id="zip_code" name="zip_code">
                            </div>

                            <input type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-success" value="CHECKOUT" action = "checkout" id="submit">
                        </div>



                </div>
                </form> 
            </div>
```

script code

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){

        $('#submit').click(function(){


        var name = $('#name').val();
        var email = $('#email').val();
        var address = $('#address').val();
        var city = $('#city').val();
        var state = $('#state').val();
        var card_name = $('#card_name').val();
        var cvv = $('#cvv').val();
        var card_number = $('#card_number').val();
        var expired_month = $('#expired_month').val();
        var zip = $('#zip_code').val();

        var data_string ='name='+ name + '&email=' + email + '&address=' + address + '&city=' + city + '&state=' + state + '&card_name=' + card_name + '&cvv=' + cvv + '&card_number=' + card_number + '&expired_month' + expired_month + '&zip' + zip_code ;


        $.ajax({
            url : "action1.php",
            method : "POST",
            data :data_string,
            success:function(data){
                $('#checkout_form').html("<div id='message'></div>");
                $('#message').val("form submitted");
            }
        });
    });
});
    </script>
```

action1.php

```
<?php

include('database_connection.php');

if(isset($_POST['submit']){

        $data = array(
            ':name' => $_POST['name'],
            ':email' => $_POST['email'],
            ':address' => $_POST ['address'],
            ':city' => $_POST['city'],
            ':state' => $_POST['state'],
            ':card_name' => $_POST ['card_name'],
            ':cvv' => $_POST['cvv'],
            ':card_number' => $_POST['card_number'],
            ':expired_month' => $_POST['expired_month'],
            ':zip_code'=> $_POST['zip_code']
        );

        $query = "INSERT INTO checkout (name,email,address,city,state,card_name,cvv,card_number,expired_month,zip_code) VALUES (:name,:email,:address,:city,:state,:card_name,:cvv,:card_number,:expired_month,:zip_code)";

        $statement = $connect ->prepare($query);

        if($statement->execute($data))
        {
            echo "form submitted";
        }
}
?>
```

Comment: Try to console the error console.log(data),

Comment: &zip' + zip_codes   - error in this line now i removed the error but the data not store in the database

Comment: send serialized form instead string . ' data :$("#checkout_form ").serialize();'

Comment: nothing happened...

Answer (score 0):

Your form page is refreshing when submit is clicked. Do this:

```
$('#submit').click(function(e){
     e.preventDefault;
```

As stated in the comments, also:

```
echo $query;
exit; //This exit is causing the query not to run because the script stops running.
```

You have semi-colons in front of your field names. Remove them:

```
$data = array(
            'name' => $_POST['name'],
            'email' => $_POST['email'],
            'address' => $_POST ['address'],
            'city' => $_POST['city'],
            'state' => $_POST['state'],
            'card_name' => $_POST ['card_name'],
            'cvv' => $_POST['cvv'],
            'card_number' => $_POST['card_number'],
            'expired_month' => $_POST['expired_month'],
            'zip_code'=> $_POST['zip_code']
        );
```

Comment: data does not store in the data base. help me

Comment: @PrabhuMsd Your data is not saving because of `echo $query;exit;` comment this line and then check it again.

Comment: i have removed the statement...but nothing happened brother please help me im beginner

Comment: shall i also remove semicolon in insert query ?

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to the Stackoverflow @prabhu-msd

Add `e.preventDefault;` as the first line under this code:

```
$('#submit').click(function(){
```

It prevents the page to be refreshed and run your Ajax. Under success add `location.reload();` after this line `$('#message').val("form submitted");` to refresh the page once your data is submitted (If you want to refresh the page) otherwise do what ever you want.

In your PHP File, you are using exit which prevents the execution of your query. Kindly, remove that `exit`.

Comment: the data does not store in the database ...i need to store but i cannot find where the problem is

Comment: @PrabhuMsd add `console.log(data)` under success and provide the result of it. Secondly, you are using exit before the execution of the Query. Kindly remove that `exit` as well.
`echo $query;exit; `

Comment: i have removed the statement...but nothing happened brother please help me im beginner